# How to get the object class in Java?

Tags: java, performance, class, comparison

What is the best way to get the class of an instance ?

What is the recommended way ? and what are the differences (performances) between :

- Compare the class

`if( this.getClass().equals(MyClass.class) ){` 
which seems to be the same as `this.getClass() == MyClass.class`   (or perhaps using  `Class.forName("com.test.MyClass")`)

- Test the instance of *(seems to be the more readable)*

  ```
  if( this instanceof MyClass ){
  ```
- Test the instance using class

  ```
  if( MyClass.class.isInstance(myInst) ){
  ```

Comment: Your question of how to get the class and your examples of comparing classes seem to contradict. What do you want to know? How to compare types?

Comment: `Class.forName("com.test.MyClass")` should be avoided, because the `String` is harder to refactore on changes than `MyClass.class`

Comment: @nfechner I want to know which inherited class am I working on : this code is in a super class.

Comment: What do you really want to know?

Comment: You don't need `this.` in front of `getClass()`.

Comment: @edem Regardless to the answers, I think `this.getClass() == MyClass.class` is what I need, because I want to know exactly the class I am working with.

Comment: The super class shouldn't rely on details of its subclasses. Smells like bad engineering. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @OrangeDog Humm... You're right... I want to check if the user got the rights to do some stuff, on severals class, in the same way. So, I factored the code in the super class (abstract) that handles this case. 
But, now I think the super class should use an abstract method overridden in each subclass.

Comment: You could even keep most of the code in a `public` method in the superclass, and have each subclass override a `protected` method to do the bit that's different, if what you're doing makes sense like that. Otherwise maybe use a `SecurityCheck` interface or something.

Comment: You shouldn't need Reflection, or even "instanceof", much in normal programming.  An overridable method in the super is usually the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option one only tells you if the class is exactly what you are testing. This is usually not very useful. For example, it's completely pointless for interfaces. If this is actually what you want to do, you can probably use `==` unless you're messing around with different `ClassLoader`s, in which case there may be more than one instance of each `Class` object.

Option two tells you whether the object is statically assignable to the given class (i.e. can be cast to it).

Option three does the same as two, but using the [reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29). You'll only need this if you're doing dynamic typing. The built-in `instanceof` is more readable and should be much more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `this.getClass().equals( MyClass.class)` when you want to match a class exactly because `"someString" instanceOf Object` will produce true because String class is subtype of Object.

This is checking `is a` relationship between any instance and the class.

In your case any subclass of `MyClass` will produce `true`

1. `instanceof` tests whether the thing on the left is an instance of the type on the right or some subtype.
2. `getClass() == ...`tests whether the types are identical.

Comment: You may clarify too why you think your way superseeds the other possibilities